# Cannot connect to any host (including localhost) using PAC Manager on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, gnome, rpm

I'm using following system:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
$ uname -a
Linux X 3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 5 16:07:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

I'm trying to get [PAC Manager download | SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/) going. Whenever I try to run it, I'm ending up with following error:

```
Jan 29 11:09:00 X pac.desktop: PAC started (pac) with PID 21591
Jan 29 11:09:00 X pac.desktop: INFO: Used config file '/home/alexus/.config/pac/pac.nfreeze'
Jan 29 11:09:01 X pac.desktop: INFO: Using 'standard Gnome2' tray icon
Jan 29 11:09:05 X pac.desktop: *** unhandled exception in callback:
Jan 29 11:09:05 X pac.desktop: ***   Can't locate object method "new" via package "Gnome2::Vte::Terminal" (perhaps you forgot to load "Gnome2::Vte::Terminal"?) at /opt/pac/lib/PACTerminal.pm line 500.
Jan 29 11:09:05 X pac.desktop: ***  ignoring at /opt/pac/lib/PACMain.pm line 1398.
```

My company's policy prohibits me using `CPAN`, but I do have `vte` package installed:

```
$ rpm -q pac vte
pac-4.5.5.7-2.x86_64
vte-0.28.2-10.el7.x86_64
$
```

Am I missing any `RPM`? How can I resolve this?

*** UPDATE ***

`line 500` of `/opt/pac/lib/PACTerminal.pm`:

> $$self{_GUI}{_VTE} = Gnome2::Vte::Terminal -> new;

`line 1398` of `/opt/pac/lib/PACMain.pm`:

> $$self{_GUI}{connExecBtn} -> clicked;

`pac.nfreeze`:

```
$ rm -i `locate pac.nfreeze`
rm: remove regular file ‘/home/alexus/.config/pac/pac.nfreeze’? y
$
```

`iptables.service`:

```
$ systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
$
```

Comment: **/opt/pac/lib/PACTerminal.pm line 500. and /opt/pac/lib/PACMain.pm line 1398.** what do these files contain at these lines? That could shed some light on this, seems like one (or both) of these files might be outdated (unless it's a firewall problem, just to be sure did you try disabling the firewall (can you?)) there's aolso your **.../pac.nfreeze** file, it's the used config file, might be misconfigured.

Comment: @cestarian I updated my question with `line 500` from `/opt/pac/lib/PACTerminal.pm` and I removed `pac.nfreeze` as well, no firewall.

Comment: What happens when you run it this time? and you're missing **/opt/pac/lib/PACMain.pm line 1398**. You also don't need to include the rm command hehe.

Comment: @cestarian, I updated my question with line from second file as well (I apologize for missing it first time). I tried it again and still with same results (same error).

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what's up. I don't understand the syntax well enough (and even if I did I probably couldn't). But at least you have a more detailed question now :)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, but his resolved it for me:

```
sudo find /opt/pac/ -name "Vte.so*" -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: Why would deleting random files solve this?

Comment: I see VTE referenced in the question, but I too am confused as to how an apparently *missing* VTE problem would be solved by removing it. Does this version of the library conflict in some way?